# Can I set a benchmark with several data sets in R?

Tags: r, database

This is just a premature thought, but say I have X datasets, and they have Y characteristics, e.g. artificial vs. non-fictional data.

Is it possible to compute an index ranging from 0 to 1 based on the X datasets' Y characteristics? I have not conceptualised yet what exactly 1 means or 0.

Comment: This premature thought is too premature fulfilling answer to be possible. "Maybe" depending on what you mean with the first and second sentence.

Comment: You are right. I'll come back once I have something to show.